# Output by shortcode not displaying as intended using HTML

Tags: html, wordpress

I got a plug-in in Wordpress, where i have a shortcode `[foobar]` which outputs a form.

If i put the shortcode `[foobar]` inside a page in wordpress, the output shows as it should, e.g.:

```
<form>
<input></input>
</form>
```

If i put the shortcode inside a table like so:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> [foobar] </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then the output is as two elements:

```
<form>
<input></input>
</form>

<table>
<tr>
<td>  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The table is empty, and the output is displayed before the table, even though the shortcode is placed within the td element.

I tried putting the shortcode within a `<div>` tag, but same result - the shortcode is displayed before the `<div>` tag, and the `<div></div>` turns out empty.

I have no idea why this happens, maybe it is some kind of error within wordpress?
If any further information is needed, please let me know. I will gladly post the code, however i am not sure it has any relevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to execute a shortcode in your php page you have to do it with php as so:

```
<td><?php echo do_shortcode('[foobar]'); ?></td>
```

Give that a shot.

If you're doing this from the WP dashboard... it's because the shortcode itself has styles applied to it that will need to be adjusted to fit where you want to place it.

Do an inspect element on the shortcode as it prints on the page and see the styles that are associated with the shortcode and override or otherwise adjust them in your CSS.